# Watson Knowledge Catalog Data Source Connectivity

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog

Is there the ability to profile data from cloud repositories such as Azure storage, Google Storage, etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, data profiling is supported for data from cloud repositories such as Azure, AWS, Google in addition to IBM Cloud.

Those connectors are supported, and here's the full list of supported connectors in Watson Knowledge Catalog:
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/manage-data/conn_types.html?audience=wdp&context=wdp